# Prove that, for every $a\neq0$, the equations $ax^3 - x^2 -x -(a +1)= 0$ and $ax^2 - x -(a +1)=0$ have a common root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

> Show that, for every real number $a\neq0$, the equations
> $ax^3 - x^2 -x -(a +1)= 0$ and $ax^2 - x -(a +1)=0$
> have a common root.

I want to know whether there are any mistakes in it.
Proof: If the system of equations
$$ax^3-x^2-x-(a+1)=0\cdots(1)$$ and $$ax^3-x^2-x=ax^2-x\cdots(2)$$ is considered,let us see what roots are obtained. Now,Subtracting (1) and (2) we get,
$$-(a+1)=x-ax^2\Rightarrow ax^2-x-(a+1)=0$$ This equation has roots $-1$ and $(1+2a+1)\times \frac{1}{2a}=\frac {a+1}{a}$.We see that $\frac {a+1}{a}$ is the root of (1) and (2) but (-1) is not(we can verify that). Thus, we found a common root for $a$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$ with $a\neq0$.

Comment: Well, the answer is correct but I don't see where you verified that $\frac {1+a}a$ was a root of the two polynomials.  That is a simple verification, but it should be done.

Comment: To stress:  your claim that, if $p(x)=q(x)$ has a solution, then $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ must have a common root is false.  Take $p(x)=x, q(x)=2x+1$ for a simple counterexample.

Comment: @lulu got it. Thank you.I will edit that.

Comment: While your approach is correct, I don't see any reason why you need Equation (2).  Right after introducing Equation (2), you subtract Equations (1) and (2) and recover your second original equation.  This seems to go in a big circle.  So, you can cut down the work by just jumping to the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost finished the solution.  But you're missing one step.

Because, we must check that the solution satisfies at least one equation.

You can also reach the result as follows:

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}ax^3-x^2-x-(a+1)=0\\ ax^2-x-(a+1)=0\end{cases} \\\\ \implies &\begin{cases}ax^3-x^2-x-(a+1)=0\\ ax^3-x^2-x(a+1)=0\end{cases}\\
\implies &x(a+1-1)=a+1\\
\implies &x=\frac{a+1}{a} \end{align}$$

Finally, to conclude the proof, it is sufficient to check whether the root we found satisfies the quadratic equation:

$$\frac{(a+1)^2}{a}-\frac{a+1}{a}-(a+1)=0.$$

This means, you're done.